# Javascript comparison not working properly

Tags: javascript

I'm working with the billing part of my system and I put an event in my `TextBox` using javascript and I have two textboxes. First is the `cashonhand` and `change` textboxes. But what I'm wondering is why the comparison between two textboxes is not giving me the right answer. Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-pay-bill', function () {
            var cash = parseFloat(Number($('.cashonhand').val())).toFixed(2);
            var amtdue = parseFloat(Number($('.amtdue').text())).toFixed(2);
            if (cash <= amtdue) {
                alert(cash + ' ' + amtdue + ' ' +"Insufficient Cash!!!");
                return false;
            }  
            if (cash >= amtdue) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

SO what am I missing here? Here is the output when I compare `100,000` to `78,200.00`:

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is happening? You did not describe what the behavior of your code is other than to say it's not giving the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing alphabetically instead of numerically.

Note that `.toFixed()` [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

> > **Returns**
> >
> > A string representation of number that does not use exponential notation and has exactly *digits* digits after the decimal place.

You'll want to do this comparison *before* you call `.toFixed()`

```
var cash = parseFloat(Number($('.cashonhand').val()));
var amtdue = parseFloat(Number($('.amtdue').text()));
if (cash <= amtdue) {
   alert(cash.toFixed(2) + ' ' + amtdue.toFixed(2) + ' ' +"Insufficient Cash!!!");
   return false;
}
```

You can just call `.toFixed()` wherever you *display* the number in the UI, or create a separate string version of the value, such as `sCash` and `sAmtDue` or something.

Comment: Just want to ask another. Is it the same way with `parseFloat(Number($('.cashonhand').val().toFixed(2)));` ?

Comment: Doubt that'll work, since `val()` returns a *string*, which doesn't have a `.toFixed()` method.  One thing to keep in mind is JavaScript *has no* way to represent a numeric value with *n* decimal points.  You would *have* to represent that as a string.